# Scrolling problem when rotating RecyclerView 90 degrees

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an app that runs in Landscape mode. I have a RecycleView as a part of my main view. In landscape mode if i scroll gesture vertically RecycleView scrolls fine and It does not scroll when is do a horizontal scroll gesture which is what should happen normally. Then i turn my phone to portrait mode. In this case main view stays the same like in landscape orientation. I need only that RecyclerView to be rotated 90degrees. After rotation normally RecyclerView should scroll if i do a vertical scroll gesture. But i my case, RecyclerView scrolls even if I do a horizontal scroll gesture. Normally It should not happen

Here I put sample project code below,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.axis.rotaterecyclerview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java,

```
package com.axis.rotaterecyclerview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("DATA 1");
        list.add("DATA 2");
        list.add("DATA 3");
        list.add("DATA 4");
        list.add("DATA 5");
        list.add("DATA 6");
        list.add("DATA 7");
        list.add("DATA 8");
        list.add("DATA 10");
        list.add("DATA 11");
        list.add("DATA 12");

        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        getDeviceRotation();
    }

    private void getDeviceRotation() {
        SimpleOrientationListener mOrientationListener = new SimpleOrientationListener(
                this) {
            @Override
            public void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

                    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                        recyclerView.setRotation(0);
                    } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                        recyclerView.setRotation(-90);
                    }
            }
        };
        mOrientationListener.enable();
    }
}
```

SimpleOrientationListener.java,

```
package com.axis.rotaterecyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public abstract class SimpleOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {

    public static final int CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    private volatile int defaultScreenOrientation = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    public int prevOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
    private Context ctx;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context, int rate) {
        super(context, rate);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(final int orientation) {
        int currentOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
        if (orientation >= 330 || orientation < 30) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
        } else if (orientation >= 60 && orientation < 120) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
        } else if (orientation >= 150 && orientation < 210) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
        } else if (orientation >= 240 && orientation < 300) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
        }

        if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
            prevOrientation = currentOrientation;
            if (currentOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
                reportOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
        }

    }

    private void reportOrientationChanged(final int currentOrientation) {

        int defaultOrientation = getDeviceDefaultOrientation();
        int orthogonalOrientation = defaultOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                : Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        int toReportOrientation;

        if (currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            toReportOrientation = defaultOrientation;
        else
            toReportOrientation = orthogonalOrientation;

        onSimpleOrientationChanged(toReportOrientation);
    }

    /**
     * Must determine what is default device orientation (some tablets can have default landscape). Must be initialized when device orientation is defined.
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int getDeviceDefaultOrientation() {
        if (defaultScreenOrientation == CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
            lock.lock();
            defaultScreenOrientation = initDeviceDefaultOrientation(ctx);
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return defaultScreenOrientation;
    }

    /**
     * Provides device default orientation
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int initDeviceDefaultOrientation(Context context) {

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        boolean isLand = config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        boolean isDefaultAxis = rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180;

        int result = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
        if ((isDefaultAxis && isLand) || (!isDefaultAxis && !isLand)) {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Fires when orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.
     *
     * @param orientation value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    public abstract void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation);

}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java,

```
package com.axis.rotaterecyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.list = list;

        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        holder.textView.setText(list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

rv_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#E2A7A7"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I rotate device into portrait the RecyclerView also rotate by 90degrees, At that time RecyclerView not scrolling properly and it scrolls both vertically and horizontally. But the app works fine when device is on landscape.

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I made some edits to the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: please set Recyclarview LayoutManager horizontal

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

Comment: please put manifirst file code

Answer (score 1):

**please set Recyclarview LayoutManager horizontal**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

Comment: I don't want to change orientation of the RecyclerView. I added some codes to the question, can you please help me to go through the problem with that.